# Как правильно сказать: "поднять проблему" или "ставить проблему"?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно: *поднять проблему* или *ставить проблему*?

Answer (score 3):

> как правильно: поднять проблему или ставить проблему?

**В словарях отмечены оба этих варианта.**

Из "*Словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка" Морковкина:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из *"Словаря-справочника по русскому языку для иностранцев" Ловановой и Амиантовой (изд. МГУ, 1977):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из *"Учебного словаря глагольно-именных словосочетаний русского языка" Дерягиной (1987):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это все хорошо, но вопрос-то стоял "как лучше, как правильнее". И то, что Ваши источники дают только по одному, но разному, варианту, говорит о разном понимании ими или ситуации, или значения слова "проблема".

Answer (score 0):

Если из двух зол выбирать меньшее, то "поднять". "Ставят" обычно только вопрос. Хотя в абсолютной правильности выражения "поднять проблему" - тоже не уверен. Это, конечно, лучше, чем "поставить", но в тоже как-то не очень удачно получается. "Проблему" (в общепринятом понимании слова) можно обозначить, затронуть, формулировать, предложить к обсуждению.

Сказанное не касается профессионального жаргона физиков-математиков и отчасти программистов. Там "проблема" может означать некое утверждение с вопросом "Верно ли оно?". В таком понимании проблему можно как раз ставить, но вряд ли "поднять".
Вот как в [ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: *"Ставят" обычно только вопрос.* — Так ведь в толковых словарях пишут, что "проблема — это сложный вопрос, нуждающийся в исследовании...". И тут же сказано, что "её ставят". Было бы странно спорить с толковыми словарями даже в таких простых случаях.