# Какова проблема текста?

Tags: смысл, егэ, литературоведение

Можно ли было написать «автор ставит проблему приспособления человека к войне»?

---

> Когда он в первый раз выходил из землянки умываться, это не бросилось ему в глаза, а сейчас он внезапно заметил всю красоту природы в этот солнечный зимний день: и на редкость синее небо, и белизну нападавшего за ночь снега, и черные тени стволов, и даже треугольник самолетов, летевших так высоко, что их далекое, тонкое пение не казалось опасным.
>
> Только что в блиндаже они спорили между собой о войне и смерти, о том, как убивать людей, и о том, можно ли при этом быть добрым и злым…
>
> А сейчас он шел к развалинам барского дома по залитой солнцем и разлинованной тенями стволов сосновой аллее и думал, как, в сущности, плохо приспособлен человек к той жизни, которая называется войной. Он и сам пытается приучить себя к этой жизни, и другие заставляют его приучиться к ней, и все равно из этого ровным счетом ничего не выходит, если иметь в виду не поведение человека, на котором постепенно начинает сказываться время, проведенное на войне, а его чувства и мысли в минуту отдыха и тишины, когда он, закрыв глаза, может, словно из небытия, мысленно возвратиться в нормальную человеческую обстановку…
>
> Нет, можно научиться воевать, но привыкнуть к войне невозможно. Можно только сделать вид, что ты привык, и некоторые очень хорошо делают этот вид, а другие не умеют его делать и, наверное, никогда не сумеют. Кажется, он, Синцов, умеет делать этот вид, а что проку в том? Вот пригрело солнышко, небо синее, и самолеты летят куда-то не сюда, и пушки стреляют не сюда, и он идет, и ему так хочется жить, так хочется жить, что прямо хоть упади на землю и заплачь и жадно попроси еще день, два, неделю вот такой безопасной тишины, чтобы знать, что, пока она длится, ты не умрешь…

Comment: "Какова проблема текста?" Вопрос поставлен так, как будто мы обсуждаем проблемный текст. Но думается, на деле автор вопроса хотела поговорить о проблеме, которая поданята в этом тексте (рассказе).

Comment: **Можно ли было написать «автор ставит проблему приспособления человека к войне»?** — Почему "можно ли было"? Момент упущен? А что было написано на самом деле?

Comment: @М_Г наверняка автор вопроса аккурат закончил написание сочинения на ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли было написать «автор ставит проблему приспособления человека к войне»?

На мой (непрофессиональный) взгляд, такой ответ не является ошибкой. Однако лучше звучало бы не *приспособление к войне*, а  *приспособление к жизни на войне*. А если посмотреть глубже, автор говорит не о приспособлении, а о невозможности привыкнуть к войне, о несовместимости войны и человеческой природы, которая хочет жить и наслаждаться этой жизнью, а не убивать других и подвергать свою жизнь постоянной опасности.

И еще. От выражения "ставить проблему" веет запахом канцелярии. Его еще как-то можно было бы употребить в отношении публицистической статьи, но говорить так о художественном произведении неуместно. Немного лучше, но все равно неуместно "поднимать проблему" (см. [Как правильно сказать: "поднять проблему" или "ставить проблему"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422597/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)).

Если в ответе необходимо употребить слово проблема, то можно сказать, что **автор говорит (рассуждает) о проблеме (раскрывает, обнажает проблему) несовместимости войны и человеческой природы.**

Вот как-то так я бы ответил.